Angular application stop to work on iis with disabled dynamics compression
I've faced with the following behavior :
I have .net 8 web api application, that returns an angular spa application;
The .net hosted on IIS, by default dynamic compression on IIS is disabled and in that state I can see, that my web api application successfully return all angular app resources like js bundles, styles etc, after browser completed uploading that resources the spa app just stucking at the initial state, no api request or component loading happen ;
but if I enable dynamic compression on IIS everything start work as expected , why dynamic compression setting could cause such behavior ?
I don't have any specific settings around compression from .net  web api application side
Could you please help, how to troubleshoot it

Did you already compared the files the browser used? Do you see any output in the console or failed requests? I just think about, that the compression does something wrong with special characters. Did you already try to use the compression based on .net core instead of iis?

The issue you're facing seems to be related to how your Angular SPA app and .NET Web API handle resource delivery and compression settings in IIS. In the browser console, check if there are any JavaScript errors or warnings when the app gets stuck. Errors related to missing or incorrect files (e.g., syntax errors in JS files) could give clues.
